# Is there a kendo grid reference?

Tags: kendo-grid

I am starting on Kendo and trying to learn it. Then from stackoverflow I get a piece of code like

```
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
var dataRows = grid.items();
```

Visual studio does not suggest the items method when i dot. It isn't present in the watch under methods either.

Where do I find these methods the easiest way? Is there a JavaScript doc or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet will be the Telerik documentation for all of the available methods / functions, etc:

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid

Comment: Neither data() nor items() is present on the page or in the function dropdowns in the top of that page. I hope someone at least can say why they are not autocompleted in Visual Studio or present in those dropdowns. I am not so used to JavaScript so my guess is that they come from some arbitrary library.